# Making a simple Battleship game in Ruby

Tags: ruby, translate

a while back I did the Codecademy - Python track and made a simple battleship game. I've been learning Ruby now and wanted to try to convert the game from Python to Ruby. So far I've been doing well in translating, however, I'm stuck at this point trying to print an "X" on the board where the player already guessed. I've played around with different methods but so far haven't been able to achieve my goal.

The particular line I'm having trouble converting is: `board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"`

Here's the full game code (I'm aware other parts still need to be changed as well but have been going through methodically and this has been my stopping point so far, any further tips are also much appreciated!):

edit: Thanks for the info guys, I was able to get it up and running as imagined with all your help! Now I just need to figure out how to put a quit method in there..

```
def play_battleship

  board = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10, "O") }

  def print_board(board)
    board.each do |r|
      puts r.map { |p| p }.join(" ")
    end
  end


  puts "Let's play Battleship!\n-----\nYou have 10 tries!\n-----"
  print_board(board)
  def random_row(board)
      return rand(10)  
  end

  def random_col(board)
      return rand(10)  
  end

  ship_row = random_row(board)
  ship_col = random_col(board)
  #puts ship_row ##debugging purposes
  #puts ship_col ## ^^^^


  for turn in 1..10
    puts "Turn: #{turn}"
    puts "Guess Row (0-9): "
    guess_row = gets.chomp.to_i  
    puts "Guess Collumn (0-9): "
    guess_col = gets.chomp.to_i
    if turn == 10
        puts "------\nGame Over!\nThe Battleship coordinates were:#{ship_row},#{ship_col}"
        break
    elsif (guess_row == ship_row) && (guess_col == ship_col)
        puts "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
        break
    else
        if ((guess_row < 0) || (guess_row > 9)) || ((guess_col < 0) || (guess_col > 9))
            puts "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
        elsif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X")
            puts "You guessed that one already."
        else
            puts "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
              #if turn == 10
                #  puts "Game Over\nThe Battleship coordinates were:#{ship_row},#{ship_col}"
               #   break
              #end
        end
    end
    print_board(board)
  end
end
play_battleship
```

Comment: See this on multidimensional arrays: http://www.ehow.com/how_2091651_create-multidimensional-array-ruby.html You haven't created one yet

Comment: Your board is not a 2d array, it is just ten '0's. Do `board = []` then `board 10.times { board << ("0" * 10)}`

Answer (score 3):

Your current problem, as the commenters have pointed out, is that you're using a single-dimensional array as your board. Which means that if you call `board[guess_row][guess_col]`, you'll get `nil`.

Why `nil`? Because `board[guess_row]` is just the string 'O'. `'O'[guess_col]` is still valid code - it's asking for the character at index `guess_col` of the string - but the string is only one character long, so any index bigger than 0 will get you `nil`.

You should start by changing how you define `board`, so that it's either actually a multidimensional array, or by making the 'row' strings have as many characters as you expect.

Since you asked for further tips, here's some things to consider:

**Fencepost Errors:** Arrays (and Strings) in Ruby are zero-indexed. Assuming your board is a ten-element array, the rows are `board[0]` through `board[9]`. There are a number of places in the code where you instead refer to them as `board[1]` to `board[10]`, which is going to trip you up. For instance, when you select the random values where the 'Battleship' is located, you use `rand(1..10)`, when what you probably want is `rand(10)`, which returns a random integer from (slightly counterintuitively) 0 to 9. Calling `a[10]` on an Array with ten elements (indexed 0 through 9) won't produce an exception, it's just (you guessed it) `nil`.

**Object Reference:** You might be tempted to define the board like so: `Array.new(10, Array.new(10,'O'))`. If you did, you'd run into an interesting problem... setting one element to 'X' would set *every element in that column* as well. Ruby is defining the 'inner' array first, and then setting every element of the board *to that same array*. I almost didn't mention this, because it's a valuable learning experience, but I think I'll settle for leaving figuring out how to avoid this situation as an exercise to the reader.

Finally, a few random stylistic tips: Rubyists generally use `.each` instead of `for`. If you use `print` instead of `puts` for your prompt, it won't insert a newline. Ruby doesn't require an explicit `return` statement - it will return the value of the last line of the method. Try making the whole program a method, maybe named `play`.